# How to make cross-domain requests using AJAX and why they work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cors

There is a web server on my LAN, at `10.xxx`, on machine A.

I have an HTML page on machine B. This HTML page wants to make an AJAX request to the web server at `10.xxx`. I made the page (with URL of `file://abc.html`) and tried it and got

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://XXXXXXXXXXX/ajax_info.txt. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)

**My questions:**

1. Is there any way I can enable this in Mozilla?
2. How can we make requests to Facebook, Twitter, and jQuery library servers via AJAX if cross-domain requests are prohibited?
3. Can I add `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` to vanilla AJAX requests?

This is probably a common question. I have seen lots of questions similar to this on Google, and SO as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

on machine A

If you want to be more secure you can add your domain in place of the * -

http://www.foo.com for example

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.foo.com');
```

Comment: where exactly  on machine A ? basically we need to make sure that domain A always return this in its reponse ?

Comment: It's a header, you put it a t the top of your page. Above everything else.

Comment: as per my next question, does facebook has set this so any domain in world can query its domain ?

Comment: That's another separate question. Please mark the above one as correct and if you want more information ask another question or open chat with me. There is a big big difference between what you are doing and what fb is doing. Basically if you want to open your machine you should make authentications, REST API as a core, and such. Again it's whole other question so...

Comment: I agree what you are saying, I know what I am doing or what fb is doing is completely different, can you invite me on chat, i guess i cant do that

Comment: Anyone coming here for answer , read this as well :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159154/how-does-a-rest-api-work-with-javascript-when-there-is-a-same-domain-origin-poli